# Trying to generate rspec test for Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I type:

```
rails g rspec:controller application
```

But nothing appears in the spec file?

Answer (score 0):

> If you type script/rails generate, the only RSpec generator you'll
>   actually see is rspec:install. That's because RSpec is registered with
>   Rails as the test framework, so whenever you generate application
>   components like models, controllers, etc, RSpec specs are generated
>   instead of Test::Unit tests.

```
rails g rspec:integration [name]
```

1. controller
2. helper
3. install
4. integration
5. mailer
6. model
7. observer
8. scaffold
9. view

example:

```
 => rails g rspec:integration controller
 => create  spec/requests/controllers_spec.rb
```

Comment: But there is no rspec:controller generator only install and observer appear?

Comment: I find this all very confusing! Is there a guide that you can recommend that explains everything?